# Move the Add box to the top of the Interested/Ignored tag list

Tags: feature-request, tags

As the list of interesting/ignored tags expands, the position of the Add textbox is not static.  In order to add a tag to one of these lists, I have to scroll down an unknown length in order to target that textbox.

I'd suggest one of two things:  Move the textbox to below the header for each section

```
<h4>Interesting Tags</h4>
<input id="interestingTag" type="text" name="interestingTag" ...
<div id="interestingTags">
 <a href="/questions/tagged/c%23" cl…
</div>
```

or place both at the top of the Interesting Tags/Ignored Tags list

```
<input id="interestingTag" type="text" name="interestingTag" ...
<input id="ignoredTag" type="text" name="ignoredTag" ...
<h4>Interesting Tags</h4>    
<div id="interestingTags">
 <a href="/questions/tagged/c%23" cl…
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I like the add box at the bottom.  My most interesting tags should at the top of the list, not the add box, which I rarely use anymore.  If this is implemented at all it should be a user preference.